# What's the most succinct way in PHP to test if an array key is exists and save it's value?

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

This seems really clunky:

```
if (empty($xml['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['SendPurchasesResponse']['PurchasesResponse']['Status']['Code'])) {
    $status = $xml['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['SendPurchasesResponse']['PurchasesResponse']['Status']['Code'];
}
```

Is there a better way to handle "Undefined index" errors in the event that some of those array keys are missing?  As you might guess, this array is coming from an XML based API and I can't trust their response to me.

Do you think using suppressing errors using "@" is a cop out:

```
$status = @$xml['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['SendPurchasesResponse']['PurchasesResponse']['Status']['Code'];
```

Comment: Don't suppress errors. Use the answer in the cited duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would this work for you?

```
try {
  $status = $xml['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['SendPurchasesResponse']['PurchasesResponse']['Status']['Code'];
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $status = ""
}
```

Comment: I like it! I hadn't thought a PHP Notice error would be caught as an exception.